# Lots of ANRs from com.urbanairship.push.PushService, via Titanium ... why?

Tags: android, titanium, urbanairship.com, titanium-modules

We have a rather bulky Titanium app and use urban airship titanium module version 2.3.2 to handle push notifications for android.

There are no device model nor android version patterns in the Google play ANR reports..

Title of the ANR: "ANR Executing service our.apps.namespace/com.urbanairship.push.PushService"

Here's the body of the thread dumps (Via google play):
http://pastebin.com/SsacQRCH

Can I do a better job asking for help -- what other information should I provide?

Comment: Seems to be an issue with Titanium SDK 3.2.x.  The usecase is: If your app is backgrounded there's a chance that android will kill it to free up memory.  If this happens, and you have a service (like a push notification service) running that attempts to wake/resume your app...  To verify that your app has been killed, use `adb shell dumpsys activity`.  The titanium folks are, as of last night, able to reproduce it -- so hopefully a fix is on its way.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be related to this issue:

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-16538

I have had similar very intermittent problems with an app that also uses the Urban Airship module. Have tested with 3.3 release and it appears to have been solved. As with most intermittent issues though, it has been a tough one to debug. Hopefully fixed for you as well.